# Python - error when trying to compare two CSV imported dictionaries

Tags: python

I've been trying to compare two CSV files by first converting them to dictionaries. This is the code I use:

```
import csv
with open('BDP DUMMY.csv', mode='r') as infile1:
      reader1 = csv.DictReader(infile1)
      mydict1 = reader1

with open('OBP DUMMY.csv', mode='r') as infile2:
      reader2 = csv.DictReader(infile2)
      mydict2 = reader2


for k,v in zip(mydict1.items(), mydict2.items()):
      if mydict1_values == mydict2_values:
         print ('Ok', mydict1_values, mydict2_values)
      else:
         print ('Not', mydict1_values, mydict2_values)
```

However, I get an error saying:

```
'DictReader' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What do you think `mydict1 = reader1` and `mydict2 = reader2` do?

Comment: Side note: _please, **especially when working with Python**, use consistent indentation_. I see four-space, five-space, one-space, and three-space indentation being used here. In fact, I'm not even sure this code will work: the mixed five and four-space indentation in your second `open` context manager should generate an `IndentationError`.

Comment: sorry, that's just the way I copied the code on to here. On python my indentation is consistent.

Comment: We have no way of knowing which errors are relevant and which aren't. In the future, please make sure your code here _exactly_ reflects your real code. You can paste it into your question, then select it and click the `{}` button or press Ctrl+K to indent the whole thing by four spaces, causing Stack Overflow to treat it as code.

Comment: I fixed it up on here too

Comment: in terms of mydict1 = reader1 and mydict2 = reader2  and what they do I am really not too sure as I have only been using Python for a few days now

Comment: Thanks! This is better: I don't think this code will generate any `IndentationError`s. But it's still inconsistent: I see six-space indentation and three-space indentation. Don't worry about fixing it up further if it's meaningfully the same as your real code. At least it's valid now.

Comment: If you don't know what that code does, why are you using it? Are you working form a tutorial or something? It's likely that you've missed something on those lines. Hint: right now, `mydict1` is just another name for `reader1`. Same with `mydict2` and `reader2`.

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DictReader` does not return you a dict and therefore does not have the `items` attribute.

You can store your values in a list if you want to use/compare them later.

```
import csv

with open('BDP DUMMY.csv','r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    content1 = [i for i in reader]

with open('OBP DUMMY.csv','r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    content2 = [i for i in reader]

for v1,v2 in zip(content1,content2):
    if v1 == v2:
        print('OK - v1:{}, v2{}'.format(v1,v2))
    else:
        print('NOT - v1:{}, v2{}'.format(v1,v2))
```

I also used the `.format` formatting to print your variables.